# Is there a Python Function to make a permutation without repeating certain elements places?

Tags: python, permutation

I want to make a mask which can allow me to take certain values in a given data structure, without repeating positions:

For example if I have:

[0,0,0,0,1,1]

And one of the permutations, chosen at random, is:

[1,1,0,0,0,0]

I'd like that position 0 and 1 in the array not to be used in the next permutation for the ones:

[1,0,0,0,0,1] should not be allowed because position 0 is already used.

[0,0,1,0,0,1] should be allowed, because position 0 and position 1 are not being used.

And for the next permutation, it can't take position 2 and 5 because the second permutation has already taken it, so the only option that remains is:

[0,0,0,1,1,0]

I don't know if there is a built-in function that can allow me to make this:

```
fun(value_options=[0,0,0,0,1,1], number_of_combinations_to_take=3)

# Output:
[ [1,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,1,0] ]
```

Thanks in advance, have a nice day

PS: The objective of this function is to have a number of permutations that allow me to do this:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = [1,1,0,0,0,0]

Node(p +jump*a, p + jump*b, p + jump*c, p + jump*d, p +  jump*e, p + jump*f)
```

So I can move a function only in a certain direction.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to take pairs out of `random.shuffle(list(range(6)))`.

Comment: There is no built-in function to do this. Have you tried writing your own code to do it, basically by filtering unwanted material out of the date emitted by this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the restrictions, rather than generating an exhaustive list of permutations and then filtering it down after the fact, I think it makes more sense to approach this problem by shuffling a list of the indices and popping elements from that list (with no repeats) to generate the masks.

```
>>> import random
>>> def fun(v, n):
...     i = list(range(len(v)))
...     random.shuffle(i)
...     m = sum(v)
...     r = []
...     for _ in range(n):
...         p = [0] * len(v)
...         for _ in range(m):
...             p[i.pop()] = 1
...         r.append(p)
...     return r
...
>>> fun([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 3)
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam beat me to it but in case this helps you

```
def fun(n, m=2):
    assert n % m == 0  # n has to be a product of m
    l = list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(l)
    one_places = [l[m*i:m*(i+1)] for i in range(n/m)]
    ret = [[0]*n for _ in range(n/m)] # create lists with zeros
    # now insert ones where we want
    for i, p in enumerate(one_places):
        for j in p:
            ret[i][j] = 1
    return ret
```